# "Value out of range: overflow" error when executing SQL query on Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, security, sql-injection

I'm experiencing an issue with executing an SQL query for an internal CTF lab that's giving me the "value out of range: overflow" error.
The query is this :

```
update users set active = true where id = INJECTION
```

My objective is to trigger and error condition so I used this:

```
update users 
  set active = true 
where id = (select (case when (select 0)=1 then (select pow(999,9999)) else 10 end));
```

---> ERROR:  value out of range: overflow

while

```
update users 
  set active = true 
where id = (select (case when 0=1 then (select pow(999,9999)) else 10 end));
```

--> no error

why this? 0=1 is false why the subquery with the pow function is executed?

Comment: A CASE expression makes no guarantee that only relevant branches are evaluated. Btw: the whole expression could be simplified to `id = case when false then pow(...) else 10 end` there is no need to wrap every reference to a constant with a SELECT query.

Comment: Read [CASE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE) and [Expression evaluation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-EXPRESS-EVAL).